# Deleted files do not show up in the Recycle Bin

Tags: file-permissions, utorrent, recycle-bin

I was deleting old utorrent files (using Remove and Delete torrent + data). But unlike usual, the deleted files did not show up in the Recycle Bin and my hard drive space did not increase. Now I can't find those files anywhere. It's so insane

I'm so freaking frustrated, there's like 30 GB of files floating invisibly around my hard drive that can't be deleted or recovered

PLease somebody help me!

Comment: Did you move the files after downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch the state of your CmStick from local disk to removable disk.
You can change this with tool “Code Meter Disc Configuration”.
Start->All Programs->CodeMeter->Tools->Disc Configuration, then go to the rider “Option” and change the value “Disk Type”.

Last step is to unplug the CodeMeter and replug it in and it should work.

Comment: Another answer can be
Open a command prompt with administrator privilege.

In the command prompt, type rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin and press Enter. [NOTE: For the other hard drive letters, substitute C: for the other hard drive letter instead. For example: rd /s /q E:\$Recycle.bin]

Close command prompt window.

Refresh the desktop. [NOTE: The Recycle Bin should be all right by now. If not, then repeat these steps for any other hard drive letter that you have.]

Comment: What does CmStick have to do with anything? There is no mention of it in the question.

Comment: If the files don't show up in the recycle bin then your commands will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Files exceeding the set capacity of the Recycle bin and files on some types of drives (e.g. USB flash) are deleted, rather than being moved to the Recycle Bin  (though usually after warning the user).

However, since the "deleted" files do *not* show as increased available space, the files appear to have been *hidden* rather than deleted.

1. Be sure to set display of *system* and *hidden* files to true; search for the files.
2. The files may be inside an archive or encrypted folder of set fixed size, such as Truecrypt can do. In that case, you'll have to resize the *container* to gain back disk space.